# scala: define a variable of type any in a trait

Tags: scala, types, annotations, traits

I have the following code:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

case class OutputAnnotation() extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation

trait SimpleTrait {

    var probe: Any 

    def outputs(): List[String] = {
        val ouputs: List[String] = Nil
        outputs
    }
}

class WorldProbe {
    @OutputAnnotation
    var population: Int = 0

    @OutputAnnotation
    var gdp: Float = 0

    var notIntersting: String = ""
}

class World extends SimpleTrait {
    var probe: Any = new WorldProbe
}

object Test {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        var w: World = new World
        var outp = w.outputs() 
    }
}
```

The idea is to have some classes which all implement some trait, SimpleTrait, which should require them to define a variable probe of Type ... hmm, the type is not really cleear, as every Class that implements SimpleFeature will come with its own Probe Type. Therefore, the only typ I could give to probe in SimpleTrait is Any. The given code compiles, but executing leads to a stackoverflow error at runtime. 
On a side note, I would like to get all variables from the probe class which are annotated with the output annotation. How could I do so?

Thanks!

Comment: The stack overflow is simply because you misspelled the `val ouputs` (instead of `outputs`), which causes the second line to actually call the same method recursively ad vitam aeternam.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with an abstract type something like this

```
trait Sim {
    type Probe
    var probe: Probe
}

class WorldProbe

class World extends Sim {
    type Probe = WorldProbe
    var probe: Probe = new WorldProbe
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your stack overflow is because of your `outputs` method. For some reason the compiler is not grabbing the variable `outputs` but instead recursively calling the method. Here is that fix specifically:

```
def outputs(): List[String] = {
  Nil
}
```

In terms of structure I'd prefer seeing SimpleTrait have a generic parameter like so:

```
trait SimpleTrait[T] {
  var probe: T

  def outputs(): List[String] = Nil
}

class World extends SimpleTrait[WorldProbe] {
  var probe: WorldProbe = new WorldProbe
}
```

And for finding all instances of your `@OutputAnnotation`, there are a few things. 1) Use Java Annotations instead of Scala Annotations (everybody does it).

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface OutputAnnotation {
}
```

Then 2) Use Jackson's Annotation Introspector to easily find and spit out the values.

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.{AnnotatedClass, JacksonAnnotationIntrospector}

    val x = new WorldProbe

    val introspector = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector
    val ac = AnnotatedClass.construct(x.getClass, introspector, null)

    val outFields = ac.fields().filter(_.hasAnnotation(classOf[OutputAnnotation]))
    for (field <- outFields) {
      field.fixAccess()
      println(field.getName + " => " + field.getValue(x))
    }
  }
}
```

Which yields this output:

```
population => 0
gdp => 0.0
```